# Hovering over an image makes that image the full-screen background

Tags: html, css, background, hover, effect

So on my blog I want to have a standard background (etc. black color), then when I hover over a random image displayed on my blog then that image becomes a full-screen background.

What I have used is the following:

```
{block:ifphotoeffect}<div id="changer"></div>{/block:ifphotoeffect}

#changer  { top: 0px; 
left: 0px;
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/mqkrxog/PPan52qgn/transparent.png)top left fixed repeat; 
background-size: cover; 
position: fixed;
z-index: -9999999999; 
opacity: 1; 
-webkit-transition:all 0.6s;
-moz-transition:all 0.6s; 
-ms-transition:all 0.6s; 
-o-transition:all 0.6s;  
transition:all 0.6s; }
```

though nothing happens..

Comment: Ever thought of adding #changer:hover { } ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need something like this?

```
#changer {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: url(http://www.pooltile.com.au/Light%20Grey%20Granite/Pictures/Thumb/LtGreyTile.jpg);
  -webkit-transition: background 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background 1s ease-out;
  transition: background 1s ease-out; 


}


#changer:hover   { top: 0px; 
left: 0px;
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
background: url(http://www.pooltile.com.au/Light%20Grey%20Granite/Pictures/Thumb/LtGreyTile.jpg) left fixed repeat; 
background-size: cover; 
position: fixed;
z-index: -9999999999; 



 }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ueDyX/1/)**

For multiple images it'd be most convenient to use JS/Jquery

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ueDyX/3/) what you require?

I used Hristo Georgiev's answer and altered it so that it alters the background of a DOM element, instead of moving the current div bellow all others (I used a div, but you can do the same for the page body).

It requires JS and Jquery though, but the jquery part can be transformed into pure JS. AS is something quite simple:

```
function cb(x){
    $('#yourBodyElement').css({'background-image':($(x).css('background-image'))});
}

function rest(){
    $('#yourBodyElement').css({'background':'blue'});
}
```

Not sure if you'll like it, but It is a solution to your problem.

Comment: Adash, can be done without JQuery if it is only one image:
http://jsfiddle.net/yrKRX/203/

 (it can be done with more images without JQuery as well, but you have to write a separate id for each)

Comment: I admit, your solution does seem more elegant. :)

Answer (score 0):

You must write:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>



#changer  {
top:0px; 
left:0px;
height:40%; 
width:40%; 
background-image:url(1.jpg);
background-position:left top fixed;
background-size: cover; 
position: fixed;
z-index: -9999999999; 
opacity: 1; 
-webkit-transition:all 0.6s;
-moz-transition:all 0.6s; 
-ms-transition:all 0.6s; 
-o-transition:all 0.6s;  
transition:all 0.6s; }   


#changer:hover   { 
top: 0px; 
left: 0px;
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
background-image: url(1.jpg) left fixed repeat; 
background-size: cover; 
position: fixed;
z-index: -9999999999; 



 }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="changer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```